# Restrict access to IP address range

Tags: htaccess, ip-address, localhost, intranet

I’m trying to restrict access to a web resource to the intranet of a company via `.htaccess`. Unfortunately, the approach via `Allow from …` isn’t working for me and and I don’t understand subnets well enough to troubleshoot the issue.

My IP address is (replaced the first two blocks for privacy) 1.2.70.59, the netmask is given by `ifconfig` as 0xffff0000, i.e. 255.255.0.0. I’ve used an IP address calculator go get the subnet from this.

[An answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913035/1968) led me to believe that the following should work:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

Or, using CIDR (only showing the last line):

```
Allow from 1.2.0.0/16
```

Neither works. Nor does the following work, [as implied by answer on this very site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/19502/13625):

```
Allow from 1.2
```

In fact, not even the following works:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But this *does* work:

```
Allow from localhost
```

Although I thought these two to be equivalent. Clearly, I have a gap in my understanding.

For completeness, this is the output of `ifconfig | grep inet[^6]`:

```
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
inet 1.2.70.59 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 1.2.255.255
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was that I accessed the website via `localhost/path/to/site` rather than `1.2.70.59/path/to/site`. Once I changed that, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

First off, are you adding these directives in an .htaccess file or a config file? If the latter, then you need to restart Apache.

Secondly, do you have mod_authz_host enabled? In your httpd.conf, there should be a line like:

```
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

Lastly, are you sure it's not working? I.e. are you testing the right path/server? Are you sure a rewrite rule or custom error page isn't making it look like you've gained access to the page even though you're being shown a different page? Also, what's not working? Is it giving access to external IPs or denying access to internal IPs?

Clear your access log (delete the file), restart the server, and test the URL once more; then look at the access log and see what IP address was recorded and what response code was given.

There are other ways of doing it (e.g. via mod_rewrite or `SetEnvIf`/`Allow from env=`), but what you're doing should work.

Comment: Actually I’m already using `SetEnvIf` for a different purpose since I only want to restrict access to a single (non-physical) resource and I don’t have write access to the server’s `httpd.conf` so I cannot use `<Location>`. Now, the solution of the puzzle is that I was using the wrong IP address to access the server – via `localhost` rather than my local network.

Comment: @Konrad: Fairly common mistake. That's why it's always worth the effort to check the access logs.

Comment: I’d love to. Unfortunately I don’t have access to it. :-( The server configuration is irking me more and more … Apache 1, PHP 5.0 (full of bugs) …

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the .htaccess file:

```
order allow,deny
#partial ip addresses blocking
deny from 192.168
deny from 219

#full ip addresses blocking
deny from 64.120.232.114
deny from 64.120.141.34
allow from all
```

Comment: Actually, I want the opposite – block from everywhere *except* from a given range. The question is how I specify the range, since my approaches of notating the subnet don’t work.

Comment: Then do: `order deny,allow` and do `allow from 127.0.0.1` and such. Just switch the allows and deny's

Comment: But that’s exactly what I’m already doing, and it’s not working.

Comment: In your httpd.conf, is there a line saying allow-override none, specifically near an IP-restricting code like in my post? If so, change to "allow-override all"

Comment: No. Otherwise, `Allow from localhost` wouldn’t work either.

Comment: I meant, the .htaccess is really just an override from the httpd.conf, if you don't allow any overrides then .htaccess won't work right. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: True but I definitely allow overrides. I actually succeed in overriding access – otherwise I couldn’t deny access (but I can), nor allow access for localhost (but I can). It just doesn’t work for IP addresses.

Comment: I've never had that happen before, maybe someone else will post.